# Merge in vs merge into

Tags: meaning

There are 3 topics and i will say "`These topics can merge in one page`" OR "`These topics can merge into one page`". Which one of them are correct?

Comment: "These topics can be merged into one page" is what I would use

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both statements are correct, but they mean different things.

> ***These topics can merge in one page*** suggest that on a certain unspecified page, the three topics merge in a kind of synthesis.

If, instead of some highly focused confluence of ideas, you seek to say that through editing you are going to pull three distinct ideas into one brief document, use the other.

> ***These topics can merge into one page*** implies that three diverse topics have been reduced to a single page.

Of the two, the second is probably the more likely.

Comment: A +vote with a note: "merge into one page" might be better as "merge to become one page" (not part of the original question) because "into one page" conveys a hint that the page already exists, as with "merge into the darkness" at http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/merge#merge__8